# ¿Como puedo mostrar los valores de un Dictionary en un foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como podria obtener los datos con razor de un ViewBag donde lstFact trae nombre, consecutivo y factura.

Espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias.

```
                   <table>
                        @foreach (var item in (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)ViewBag.lstFact)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Consecutivo

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Factura
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Nombre
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
```

Comment: Indica por favor en la pregunta, lo que asignas a `ViewBag.lstFact` en el Controlador. También indica el Modelo de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Suministraste muy poca información, pero supongo que quieres hacer esto

```
<table>
    @foreach(var item in (Dictionary<string, TuClase>)ViewBag.lstFact)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Value.Consecutivo
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Value.Factura
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Value.Nombre
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Reemplazar TuClase por la clase que tiene esas propiedades